# H2. Insert String to VARBINARY(255)

Tags: sql, database, insert, h2, varbinary

I have problems with adding data to h2 table, into a column of type `VARBINARY(255)`.

Table `USER`

```
 ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL auto_increment
 USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ROLES VARBINARY(255) NOT NULL
```

Trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO USER (username, password, roles) 
VALUES ('admin', '123', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

and this

```
INSERT INTO USER (username, password, roles) 
VALUES('admin', '123', CONVERT('ROLE_ADMIN', VARBINARY(255));
```

and a lot of another variations. All throw a "Syntax error" in SQL statement

Break my mind... Help please!

Comment: and what's the question  ?  .and you have an error?  ..  wrong result?  ..no result?  ..

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html

Comment: I have already read this documentation. But there is no word about VARBINARY. In my second i have another varbinary column Date. And i can't add data to it too... (((

Comment: seems that H2 don't admin  VARBINARY ..  then you  should use others data type

Comment: are there really no other options?

Comment: for store binary you can use binary of blob  ..  +

Comment: Lets try to explain my situation. I'm working on Java project using SpringBoot + H2. I have 2 entities Tasks and Users. Spring automatically generates tables for me. And it generates 2 columns with type of varbinary. Thats why i can't use blob or another type of data, only varbinary. In java i'm adding data without problems. Problems begin when trying to add data via H2 console or from sql script. I'm doing it because i want to integrate Flyway to my project.

Answer (score 3):

You can use H2's [STRINGTOUTF8()](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#stringtoutf8) function.

Here is what your example would look like

```
INSERT INTO USER (username, password, roles) 
VALUES('admin', '123', STRINGTOUTF8('ROLE_ADMIN'));
```